# Como desativar checkbox sem usar disabled?

Tags: html, checkbox, input

Como eu poderia inibir a alteração de um `checkbox` sem usar `disabled`, tendo em vista que eu quero enviá-lo via form.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" readonly="readonly" checked="checked"/> 
// esta alterando
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/> 
// não envia pelo form
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem usar a propriedade padrão **disabled** você pode por um return no `onclick`.

Isso acontece pois ao usar `return false` interrompe o evento click que altera o valor do checkbox.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" checked="checked" onclick="return false;"/> Teste
```

**Referência:** [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar sua solução, mas encontrei na sua referência outra solução que pro meu caso em particular se adequou melhor. Compartilhei também.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso de forma criativa usando um campo oculto.

Suponha que você quer desativar o seguinte checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkIdoso" name="chkIdoso" checked />
```

Então você pode fazer:

```html
<!-- Campo oculto que armazena o valor -->
<input type="hidden" id="chkIdoso" name="chkIdoso" value="on" />
<!-- Campo exibido para o usuário -->
<input type="checkbox" id="chkIdosoVisual" name="chkIdosoVisual" checked disabled />
```

**Referência:** [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971018/1657502)